# Displaying trajectories on rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing my own implementation of a local planner which generates 7 trajectories and choose one of them. I want to display all the 7 trajectories on rviz each time the local planner is invoked along with the trajectory chosen with a different colour. How to do it in ROS ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226326/displaying-trajectories-on-rviz/) by [mayank_m](https://answers.ros.org/users/24140/mayank_m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is what [Markers](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker) are made for. The [Tutorial on Points and Lines](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Points%20and%20Lines) should be a good stating point, as it is pretty similar to your application.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0